# Django filtering models in Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

**Models.py**

```
class AdmissionStudent(models.Model):
   studentlabel = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False, blank = False)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.studentlabel


class AdmissionRequirement(models.Model):
   requirementstudent = models.ForeignKey(AdmissionStudent, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = 
     False, blank = False)
   requirementparagraph = models.TextField(null = False, blank = False)

   def __str__(self):
       return '{} - {}'.format(self.requirementstudent, self.requirementparagraph)
```

**Views.py**

```
def admission(request):
   header = AdmissionHeader.objects.first()
   student = AdmissionStudent.objects.all()
   requirement = AdmissionRequirement.objects.all()


   context = {
       'header': header,
       'student': student,
       'requirement': requirement,
       'title':'Admissions'
       }

   return render(request, 'pages/admission.html', context)
```

**Admission.html (template)**

```
{% for student in student %}
   <b>{{ student.studentlabel }}</b><br>
   {% if {{ student.studentlabel}} == {{requirement.requirementstudent }} %}
       {% for requirement in requirement %}
           {{ requirement.requirementparagraph }}<br>
       {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I know what I did in my template is stupid, but i really don't know how to filter Admission Requirements for enrollment.

Below is an example of how I want it to appear:

**Transferee**

-1st requirement

-2nd requirement

-3rd requirement

**Foreign Student**

-1st requirement

-2nd requirement

-etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get the all the `AdmissionStudent`s, and prefetch all of the related `AdmissionRequirement` per student.

With that, you don't need `requirement = AdmissionRequirement.objects.all()`. You just need to pass your student list in the template like this:

```
student = AdmissionStudent.objects.all().prefetch_related('admissionrequirement_set')
context = {
    ...
    'student': student,
    ...
}
```

And then in your template, use the related data for requirements from student to display:

```
{% for student in student %}
   <b>{{ student.studentlabel }}</b><br>
   {% for requirement in student.admissionrequirement_set.all %}
       {{ requirement.requirementparagraph }}<br>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped a lot, i just removed an "underscore" in ```admission_requirement_set``` and it was great. Thanks again

Comment: Yes you're right the underscore shouldn't be there. Glad to help!